# How get rid of old values used inside addEventListener when addEventListener invoked the second time?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

This is the simplified version of my actual code.

There are three checkboxes and buttons (each numbered 0, 1, 2) and a submit button. Put it simply, if you check checkbox number 1 and 2, click submit, button 1 and 2 will be colored. Now you could click any of the colored buttons, it should print `1,2` into the console.

If you put any other combination of checked checkboxes it should work the same way.

```js
// There are 3 buttons (outside submt button), each corresponds to each 3 checkboxes.
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
var buttons = [btn1, btn2, btn3];


document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

  // Info which checkbox are checked is in "checkedIdx"
  const checkedIdx = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
      checkedIdx.push(i);
    }
  }

  // Initialize button color.
  buttons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  });

  // Set color=yellow to button that corresponds checked checkbox.
  for (let j = 0; j < checkedIdx.length; j++) {
    buttons[checkedIdx[j]].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    buttons[checkedIdx[j]].addEventListener("click", () => {

      // Print which checkbox checked
      console.log(checkedIdx + " ");
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb0" />
<label for="cb0"> 0 </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
<label for="cb1"> 1 </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
<label for="cb2"> 2 </label><br>

<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Submit"><br>

<input type="button" id="btn1" value="0"><br>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="1"><br>
<input type="button" id="btn3" value="2"><br>
```

The code runs as intended *visually* but what bugs me is that the button when clicked also prints indexes of previous submit session. So if you check checkbox number 1 and 2, click submit, click button, it would print `1,2`. Now you do it again, but uncheck checkbox number 1, it would print:

```
1,2
2
```

It seems that `addEventListener` attached to the button for the second time when it goes for the second submit. Now I suppose that using loop like this is a wrong way to achieve my intended scenario, but I couldn't think any better approach.

Any suggestion?

Comment: @NickParsons Hi, I have rephrased the entire question and made a simpler reproducible code snippet. Hope you understand the question now.

Comment: To clarify, console.log is just to show that the problem I addressed is in the variable `checkedIdx`. My intention is that `checkedIdx` should contain only recent information and could get rid of information from the previous submit. According the example below code snippet, `console.log(checkedIdx)` should only print `2` not `1,2` then `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that each time you click "submit" you're adding additional event listeners to the same button, causing you to see previous values as you're activating the new event listeners as well as the old ones. One option could be to remove the event listeners, but this becomes messy as you need to keep a reference to the function you pass to `addEventListener()`. Instead, I suggest you add an event listener to all your numbered buttons, but only run the code within it if it passes a condition - that is, that the button which has clicked has a `value` that is within `checkedIdx`:

```js
// There are 3 buttons (outside submt button), each corresponds to each 3 checkboxes.
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

// Make your array global so you can access it within other functions
const checkedIdx = [];
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  checkedIdx.length = 0; // clear the array each click
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
      checkedIdx.push(i);
    }
  }
  // Initialize button color.
  buttons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  });

  // Set color=yellow to button that corresponds checked checkbox.
  for (let j = 0; j < checkedIdx.length; j++) {
    buttons[checkedIdx[j]].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
});

// Add an event listener to all buttons to start with
// Control which ones activate based on whether their `value` can be found
// within your checkedIdx array. 
buttons.forEach(btn => {
  const value = Number(btn.value);
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(checkedIdx.includes(value)) {
      console.log(checkedIdx +""); // code here that you want to perform. This could invoke another function etc...
    }  
  });

});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb0" />
<label for="cb0"> 0 </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
<label for="cb1"> 1 </label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
<label for="cb2"> 2 </label><br>

<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Submit"><br>

<input class="btn" type="button" id="btn1" value="0"><br>
<input class="btn" type="button" id="btn2" value="1"><br>
<input class="btn" type="button" id="btn3" value="2"><br>
```